# docker-compose wurstmeister/kafka failing to parse KAFKA_OPTS

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, jaas, sasl

I have a basic docker-compose file file for wurstmeister/kafka

I'm trying to configure it to use SASL_PLAIN with SSL
However I keep getting this error no matter how many ways I try to specify my jaas file

This is the error I get

```
[2018-04-11 10:34:34,545] FATAL [KafkaServer id=1001] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaServer' or 'sasl_ssl.KafkaServer' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

These are the vars I have. Last one is where I specify my jaas file

```
environment:
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  KAFKA_HOST_NAME: 10.10.10.1
  KAFKA_PORT: 9092
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9093
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 10.10.10.1
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,SASL_SSL://:9093
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://10.10.10.1:9092,SASL_SSL://10.10.10.1:9093
  KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
  KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
  SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
  KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /kafka.server.truststore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: password
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /kafka.server.keystore.jks
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: password
  KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: password
  KAFKA_OPTS: '-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf'
```

Also when I try to check the docker logs I see

```
/usr/bin/start-kafka.sh: line 96: KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config: bad substitution
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: They have fixed it and it is merged now!

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/pull/321

There's a bug open now with wurstmeister/kafka but they have gotten back to me with a workaround as follows

> I believe his is part of a larger namespace collision problem that
>   affects multiple elements such as Kubernetes deployments etc (as well
>   as other KAFKA_ service settings).
>
> Given you are referencing an external file /kafka_server_jaas.conf,
>   i'm assuming you're OK adding/mounting extra files through; a
>   work-around is to specify a CUSTOM_INIT_SCRIPT environment var, which
>   should be a script similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
This is executed after the substitution part that is failing.
```

> This could have been done inline, however there is currently a bug in
>   how we process the environment, where we need to specify the input
>   separator to make this work correctly.

Hopefully this works!

Comment: Actually the above doesn't work still in talks about the issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

equals '=' inside the last value is causing this issue.
KAFKA_OPTS: '-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf'

This is what I have got after debugging.

```
+ for VAR in $(env)
+ [[ KAFKA_OPTS=- 
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf =~ ^KAFKA_ ]]
+ [[ ! KAFKA_OPTS=- 
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf =~ 
^KAFKA_HOME ]]
++ echo KAFKA_OPTS=- 
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf
++ sed -r 's/KAFKA_(.*)=.*/\1/g'
++ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
++ tr _ .
+ kafka_name=opts=-djava.security.auth.login.config
++ echo KAFKA_OPTS=- 
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/kafka_server_jaas.conf
++ sed -r 's/(.*)=.*/\1/g'
+ env_var=KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config
+ grep -E -q '(^|^#)opts=-djava.security.auth.login.config=' 
/opt/kafka/config/server.properties
start-kafka.sh: line 96: KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config: bad 
substitution
```

and this is the piece of code that is performing this operation.

```
88  for VAR in $(env)
89  do
90    if [[ $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_ && ! $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_HOME ]]; then
91      kafka_name=$(echo "$VAR" | sed -r 's/KAFKA_(.*)=.*/\1/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr _ .)
92      env_var=$(echo "$VAR" | sed -r 's/(.*)=.*/\1/g')
93      if grep -E -q '(^|^#)'"$kafka_name=" "$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties"; then
94          sed -r -i 's@(^|^#)('"$kafka_name"')=(.*)@\2='"${!env_var}"'@g' "$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties" #note that no config values may contain an '@' char
95      else
96          echo "$kafka_name=${!env_var}" >> "$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties"
97      fi
98    fi
99
100    if [[ $VAR =~ ^LOG4J_ ]]; then
101      log4j_name=$(echo "$VAR" | sed -r 's/(LOG4J_.*)=.*/\1/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr _ .)
102      log4j_env=$(echo "$VAR" | sed -r 's/(.*)=.*/\1/g')
103      if grep -E -q '(^|^#)'"$log4j_name=" "$KAFKA_HOME/config/log4j.properties"; then
104          sed -r -i 's@(^|^#)('"$log4j_name"')=(.*)@\2='"${!log4j_env}"'@g' "$KAFKA_HOME/config/log4j.properties" #note that no config values may contain an'@' char
105      else
106          echo "$log4j_name=${!log4j_env}" >> "$KAFKA_HOME/config/log4j.properties"
107      fi
108    fi
109  done
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't really answer how do I configure this value currently.

Comment: You can do following steps to overcome this situation:
1: Create a Dockerfile

Comment: You can do following steps to overcome this situation:
1: Create a Dockerfile <br/> 2: Extend the original docker image <br/>3. Create a new script where you append required option in "$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties" <br/> 4: Copy new script and change docker entrypoint <br/> 5: Do not set environment variable for KAFKA_OPTS in docker-compose.yml